# Get value from JSON into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I have data being pulled from a JSON file, and then i have a JavaScript file that draws a graph.

Here is the JSON file:

[image]

Here is my JavaScript code to draw a graph:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
  //alert('aa00'~
  $('.error').hide();
  $(".buttonSala").click(function() {
    // validate and process form here
    $('.error').hide();
    var canal = $("#canalSala option:selected").val();
    var datai = $("#datainisala").val(); 
    var dataf = $("#datafimsala").val(); 

    //alert(canal);
    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( "getSala.php", { canal: canal, dataini: datai, datafim: dataf } );

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(
      function(data) {
        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data).channels[canal].values;
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
          var dataArray = [["ts", 'values']];

          for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            var tempArray = [jsonData[i].ts, parseFloat(jsonData[i].value.replace(",", "."))];
            dataArray.push(tempArray);
          }

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
            dataArray
          );

          var options = {
            hAxis: {title: "Data/Hora", titleTextStyle: {color: "#333"}},
            vAxis: {title: "Temperatura", titleTextStyle: {color: "#333"}}
          };

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_divsala'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        });
      });
    return false;
  });
});
```

As you can see the graph is draw correcly:

[image]

In this part:

```
var dataArray = [['ts', 'values']];
```

It uses the ts data to draw, and the "Values" is what appears on the graph, on the left side, and on the line description. How can i access the JSON proprety "chname" to populate the graph description with that information? in this case "oxigénio (%) no interior do pipo de madeira 4".

I've tried everything and i cant get it to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the json property `chname` with `response.channels[canal].info.chname`, where `obj` is the **entire object from the json file**.

So, replace these lines:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data).channels[canal].values;
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var dataArray = [["ts", 'values']];
```

with this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
var jsonData = response.channels[canal].values;
var desciption = response.channels[canal].info.chname;
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    dataArray = [["ts", desciption ]];
```

Comment: I didn't notice that you are overwriting `jsonData` with `jsonData = jsonData.channels[2].values;`. My updated answer should work.

Comment: Still not working. I updated my script to match my updated one, because im using some variables to change the curl that gets the json data. But its basically the same. Instead of response.channels[2].info.chname i tried response.channels[canal].info.chname, since thats the name of the variable that contains the current canal, but still no luck @asemahle

Comment: If my edit doesn't work, you should `console.log` the `response` variable. You want to find the property path that goes to `chname`, and set `description` equal to that value.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ajax with dataType json. Data return into object. In my case I add **success** to get data when request successfully. For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getData.php",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType : "json",
  success: function (data) {
    data.forEach(function(object){
      //your code logic here

    });
  }
});
```